# Does webrtc and video chat system need to be served over https necessarily?

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

It seems that browsers wouldn't let you get hold of camera and microphone (media devices) unless you site is being served over https (correct me if I'm wrong).
So does that mean our signaling server(was://) has to run over https as well?
(I'm using peers server specifically as my signaling server).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The signalling server has to be HTTPS as well. HTTP and HTTPS differ in their security, HTTPS being more secure. That's why it is a good idea to always use HTTPS.